# Automatic transfer switch for honda eu7000 generator?

Tags: generator

Is there a reliable automatic transfer switch for the honda eu7000 generator? I'm looking for something that automatically starts the generator without any user intervention.

We have a manual transfer switch, but every time the electricity goes or comes back, my 70+ y.o. parents have to go through a bunch of steps. One of those steps is going up and down a flight of stairs.

I'm looking for an automatic transfer switch that does everything by itself. In other words, there's no need to do anything when we lose power or when it comes back.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which transfer switch you have now, and why you find it such a pain to use?

Comment: What you like to achieve and what features do you want?

Comment: Good edit.  What you hope to achieve is "over the moon" for any generator in that class of product.  Not least even if everything else were possible, how's this thing going to get gasoline?  Because I guarantee if they don't like climbing a flight of stairs, they are NOT gonna like driving out to the gas station, unloading four California cans out of their trunk, lifting the now-40lb. cans  back into the trunk, then lugging them to the generator and defeating the anti-usage valves to actually pour gas into a hot generator.  You may need to reboot this whole concept.

Comment: I agree with @Harper.  You should look at generators that are designed to be permanently installed and provide automatic backup power.  A portable generator like the Honda EU7000 just isn't going to meet your needs.  In addition to lugging fuel around, your parents would also need to visit the generator every time they want to start or stop it.  And they wouldn't be able to use it in the rain unless you build a shelter for it.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any automatic transfer switch will work so long as it meets or exceeds the KVA and voltage requirements. The biggest problem with an ATS is that they are cost prohibitive for such a small genset. It would probably cost as much as the genset and it would require a maintenance package to keep it working for when it would be needed. Also is does the generator start automatically or is it manual? because if it is not compatible to an auto start an ATS will do you no good.

Comment: I'm not sure if the generator starts automatically or if it's manual. It's a Honda EU7000.

Comment: With that model, you'll need to visit the generator every time you want to start or stop it.  If you plan on leaving it in one spot all the time, you'll need to build a weather resistant shelter that provides adequate ventilation.